# Tool for users to check thier permission (without full control)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I want to be able to empower my users to know what type of permissions to ask for.  So one step is for them to understand the permissions they already have.  But there doesn't seem to be a way for a regular user to check their own permission levels.  Does anyone know of script that can be added to a page so a user can just click a button and have their permissions displayed?  This should work for any level (and will hopefully transfer to 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following articles:

[How to Know Your SharePoint Permissions](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-know-your-sharepoint-permissions/)

[How to Check User Permission](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678653/How-to-check-user-permission-for-the-web-list-or-S)

Comment: This won't help much.  I need a solution where any user, no matter their permissions, can check exactly what permissions they have and for what sites.  (Example: a user can click a button and it tells them where they have contribute permissions for site A, read only for site B and contribute for library C).  OOB solution only works if you have full control an only for the current site.  The other solution, while I sort of understand the code does not make mention if a regular user can utilize it nor how to deploy it to a page or such.  I would need more details on this.